# How to make Core Data sync with CloudKit immediately (1 to 2 seconds) with Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently it takes about 10 to 20 seconds for my Core Data CloudKit store to sync across multiple devices.

This is my current Core Data stack:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
static let shared = PersistenceController()

static var preview: PersistenceController = {
    let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
    let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
    }
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
    return result
}()

let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

func save() {
    if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
        try? container.viewContext.save()
        try? container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
    }
}

init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "NewApp")
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!
    description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    
    do {
        try container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
    } catch {
        fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to pin viewContext to the current generation:\(error)")
    }
}
}
```

What would be the best way for me to make core data sync to iCloud immediately when there are new changes (seeing an update after about 1 to 2 seconds)?  If this is not possible, how could I make something custom to handle this?

Thank you for any help or suggestions in advance.